How to add a test case for server side validation using jest on a graphql endpoint running on express
What I need is to handle all the combinations of input values using jest. The combination of inputs are given below
const inputVariations =[
    {email:"",password:""},
    {email:"test":password:"232"},
    {email:"test.testsite.com",password:"StrongPasswd234"}
];

Validation response from api end point is showing as follows
case 1: 
{
    success : false,
    errors  : [
        {field:"email",message:"Email is required."},
        {field:"password",message:"Password is required."},
    ]
}


case 2: 
{
    success : false,
    errors  : [
        {field:"email",message:"Enter a valid email address."},
        {field:"password",message:"Password is weak."},
    ]
}

What I need is to handle the test case of validation in one section of jest as follows
it('register validation for email and password',async () => { 

    let emailErrors = [
        "Email is required.",
        "Enter a valid email address"
    ];

    let passErrors =[
        "Password is weak.",
        "Password is required"
    ];

    inputVariations.forEach(async (input) => {

             axios({
                url: 'https://myapiendpoint/graphql',
                method: 'post',
                data: {
                query:  `mutation{emailRegister(manageInput:{
                    email : "${input.email}",
                    password: "${input.password}"
                }){
                    success
                    errors{
                        field
                        message
                    }
                }
            }`}
            }).then((result) => {
                result.data.data.emailRegister.errors.forEach((errObj) => {
                    if(errObj.field === "email"){
                        expect(emailErrors).toContain(errObj.message);
                    }
                    if(errObj.field === "password"){
                        expect(passErrors).toContain(errObj.message);                    
                    }
                });
            });
            
    });

});

I could not find a best method to handle this situation, Any help would be much appreciated
